# I'm getting 21004 as status value in reply from apple's sandbox server testing auto-renewable subscriptions in ios?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm testing In app purchase auto-renewable subscription but apple's sandbox server always returns status=21004

```
 #define SHARED_SECRET @"INSERT HERE YOUR ITUNESCONNECT SHARED SECRECT KEY FOR AUTORENEWABLE SUBCRIPTIONS RECEIPT VALIDATION"

-(void)checkReceipt {
// verifies receipt with Apple
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSString *receiptBase64 = [NSString base64StringFromData:receiptData length:[receiptData length]];
NSLog(@"Receipt Base64: %@",receiptBase64);

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                            receiptBase64,@"receipt-data",
                                                            SHARED_SECRET,@"password",
                                                            nil]
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&jsonError
                    ];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
NSError * error=nil;
NSDictionary * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",parsedData);
NSLog(@"JSON: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
// URL for sandbox receipt validation; replace "sandbox" with "buy" in production or you will receive
// error codes 21006 or 21007
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if(conn) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else {
    completionBlock(NO,@"Cannot create connection");
}
}
```

Can someone help me to get proper receipt verification?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must replace this text at the top `INSERT HERE YOUR ITUNESCONNECT SHARED SECRECT KEY FOR AUTORENEWABLE SUBCRIPTIONS RECEIPT VALIDATION` with the secret key that you get from iTunes Connect.  (obviously, don't post the full secret on Stack Overflow, though).

The secret is typically a 32 digit, alpha-numeric string that looks something like this `39fkjc38jd02mg72k9cn29dfkm39fk00` (this one is fake).

In (the new) iTunes Connect go to **My Apps** > (Then click on your app) > **In-App Purchases** > **View or generate a shared secret**

Comment: how to get secret key from itunes connect?

Comment: how to get secret key programatically from itunes connect ?

Comment: Yes. The key is constant unless you intentionally generate a new one because the old one has been stolen or compromised. I'm pretty sure you cant retrieve it programatically. Since technically it shouldn't ever have to change, you should be able to grab it by hand just once and place it in your application. Make sure to keep it safe so you don't have to change it. Try to obfuscate the key in your code for a *little* security. For ultimate security, do the verification from your server instead of from the app.

Comment: @Andrew is this shared secret is same for sandbox and production enviroment?

Comment: Yes @Bhushan, the shared secret is the same for both production and sandbox environments. The only thing that differs is which url you use for receipt verification: `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` vs. `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`.

Answer (score 1):

go to ituenes connet and then your app and then go to ManageInApp purchases and then here see the left bottom there is an option view or generate a sharedsecret here you can generate an shared secret or you can view the previous shared secret